# How can I run an addon in the service addon in Kodi with python

Tags: python, xml, add-on, xbmc, kodi

I am developing kodi add-ons using python scripts and xml's.I created an service addon will be automatically started when Kodi start.
The part that in addon.xml work for this job is in here:

```
extension point="xbmc.service" library="addon.py" start="login" />
```

When this addon.py work,a button appears in the screen.
My goal is when you pushed these button;another add-on should work.
The code section in addon.py(service addon's python script)
 I wrote to handle this part is here:

```
if control=self.button0:
    file_path=xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join("...\addons/script.helloworld\addon.py"))
xbmc.executebuiltin("xbmc.RunScript(file_path)")
```

But these errors appears in kode.log

> ERROR:CScriptInvocationManager::ExecuteAsync-Not executing
>   non-existing script file path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do this and everything should work.

```
xbmc.executebuiltin("RunScript(script.addonid)")
```